# jquery hide not working for same div class after ajax call?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

1.This is my code here i have a div class inner  which is dynamically loaded using ajax call
and after ajax call if i click the hide button it is not working.

But its working perfectly before ajax request.

so in order to overcome i just  add a outer div and hide that div this time it works..
I don't know why?

```
$( "#inner" ).replaceWith( data );  /*and*/  $( "#inner" ).hide();   //not working


$( "#inner" ).replaceWith( data );    /*and*/     $( "#outer" ).hide();  //working
```

Why we cant use the same div class ?

```
<html>
  <div id="outer">
  <div id="inner">
    <br /> <br /> <br />
  <div>  <input type="button" value="signup"  onclick="changeval();"/>
  </div>
  <br /> <br />  
  </div>
  </div>
  <input type="button" value="hide" onclick="onhide();"/>    
  <script language="javascript"> 
   function changeval(context)
   {          
     var typeval="sdsf";
     var url="sdfsdf";
     $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'htp://sscs/registration',
        data:'&typeval='+typeval+'&url='+url,
        success:function(data) { 
          $( "#inner" ).replaceWith( data );           
        }        
      });         
    }
    function onhide()
    {
      $( "#inner" ).hide();
    }
  </script>
```

Comment: Try using $("#inner").replaceWith($('#inner',data));

Comment: try .html() instead of replaceWith()

Comment: yes it worked,but i want to know why its not working when we use replace

Answer (score 1):

Use [**.html()**](http://api.jquery.com/html/)

```
 $("#inner").html(data);
```

instead of [**.replaceWith()**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/) as

> Replace each element in the set of matched elements with the provided new content and return the set of elements that was removed.

[**DEMO of replaceWith**](http://jsfiddle.net/R3Dan/), Here you can see div with second class is replace with input content.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you replace the `<div id="inner">`.

Including the div and its ID. `<div id="outer">` remains so your other hide works, it still finds that `div`.

Answer (score 0):

Use like this:

```
$( "#inner" ).replaceWith( function(){
    return $(this).data();
} );
```

Answer (score 0):

After your ajax call the #inner-div does not exist anymore. You are replacing it with the response from your ajax request .

You could use `$("#inner").html(data);` to keep the div and then hide it once you received the response.

Comment: Wrong context, sorry. Sould be html().